# Optimizing loop in xarray to calculate element coordinates

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

I am trying to run following Python code (basically tries to calculate the element coordinates of triangular mesh from surrounding node cordinates) but it is too slow. Is there any way to optimize it in terms of computation and memory footprint,

```
    node_coords = da.stack([lon, lat], axis=1)
    elem_conn = ds['tri']
    elem_coords = np.array([da.mean(node_coords[v.values-1,:], axis=0) for v in elem_conn])
```

The code runs without any issue but it is too slow especially element connections and node coordinates are big arrays. I am expecting to have better performance by optimizing code or taking advantage of parallelization under Python.

Comment: Could you provide a full reproducible example?

Comment: The entire code and required data is in here. https://gist.github.com/uturuncoglu/29075b5968afbd1805cd27ac93040d8d. Thanks for your help.